# Performing complicated matrix manipulation operations with cblas_sgemm in order to carry out multiplication

Tags: c, numpy, matrix, blas

I have 100 `3x3x3` matrices that I would like to multiply with another large matrix of size `3x5x5` (similar to convolving one image with multiple filters, but not quite).

For the sake of explanation, this is what my large matrix looks like:

```
>>> x = np.arange(75).reshape(3, 5, 5)
>>> x
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]],

       [[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]],

       [[50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
        [60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
        [65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
        [70, 71, 72, 73, 74]]])
```

In memory, I assume all sub matrices in the large matrix are stored in contiguous locations (please correct me if I'm wrong). What I want to do is, from this `3x5x5` matrix, I want to extract 3 `5x3` columns from each sub-matrix of the large matrix and then join them horizontally to get a `5x9` matrix (I apologise if this part is not clear, I can explain in more detail if need be). If I were using numpy, I'd do:

```
>>> k = np.hstack(np.vstack(x)[:, 0:3].reshape(3, 5, 3))
>>> k
array([[ 0,  1,  2, 25, 26, 27, 50, 51, 52],
       [ 5,  6,  7, 30, 31, 32, 55, 56, 57],
       [10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 60, 61, 62],
       [15, 16, 17, 40, 41, 42, 65, 66, 67],
       [20, 21, 22, 45, 46, 47, 70, 71, 72]])
```

However, I'm not using python so I do not have any access to the numpy functions that I need in order to reshape the data blocks into a form I want to carry out multiplication... I can only directly call the `cblas_sgemm` function (from the BLAS library) in C, where `k` corresponds to input B.

Here's my call to `cblas_sgemm`:

```
    cblas_sgemm(    CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasTrans, 
                    100, 5, 9, 
                    1.0,
                    A, 9,
                    B, 9, // this is actually wrong, since I don't know how to specify the right parameter
                    0.0,
                    result, 5);
```

Basically, the `ldb` attribute is the offender here, because my data is not blocked the way I need it to be. I have tried different things, but I am not able to get `cblas_sgemm` to understand how I want it to read and understand my data.

**In short, I don't know how to tell** `cblas_sgemm` **to read** `x` **like** `k`**.Is there a way I can smartly reshape my data in python before sending it to C, so that** `cblas_sgemm` **can work the way I want it to?**

I will transpose `k` by setting CblasTrans, so during multiplication, B is `9x5`. My matrix A is of shape `100x9`. Hope that helps.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are moving blocks of data around.  Why would you use `cblas_sgemm` for this?  `sgemm` does matrix multiplication.

Comment: I think I am missing something.  I understand your transformation from `x` to `k`--that's just moving blocks of data.  But what does that have to do  with the "100 `3x3x3` matrices" that you mention in the first sentence?  And what is "my matrix A" that you mention in the last sentence?

Comment: `x` is what I have, `k` is the matrix I will need to multiply with "my matrix A" that I already have... I have come up with an ad-hoc solution of allocating an intermediate buffer for copying the data into the format I want and then carrying out multiplication, but that is obviously a wasteful operation. I want to find a way of carrying out multiplication without any buffers.

Comment: I've edited my post a little, hopefully it should make more sense now! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In your example, `k` is `5x9`.  What is the shape of `A`?

Comment: Well, if you must know, I will transpose `B` by setting `CblasTrans`, so during multiplication, `B` is `9x5`. My matrix `A` is of shape `100x9`.

Comment: Please add all that to the question.  It would be great if you could write a few lines of working python/numpy code with actual arrays, and then explain that you want to accomplish the equivalent using sgemm and without using to a temporary array (if possible).

Comment: Edited again, hopefully it should be better now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In short, I don't know how to tell cblas_sgemm to read x like k.

You can't.  You'll have to make a copy.

Consider `k`:

```
In [20]: k
Out[20]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2, 25, 26, 27, 50, 51, 52],
       [ 5,  6,  7, 30, 31, 32, 55, 56, 57],
       [10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 60, 61, 62],
       [15, 16, 17, 40, 41, 42, 65, 66, 67],
       [20, 21, 22, 45, 46, 47, 70, 71, 72]])
```

In a two-dimensional array, the spacing of the elements in memory must be the same in each axis.  You know from how `x` was created that the consecutive elements in memory are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...`, but your first row of `k` contains `0, 1, 2, 25, 26, ....`.  The is no spacing between `1` and `2` (i.e. the memory address increases by the size of one element of the array), but there is a large jump in memory between `2` and `25`.  So you'll have to make a copy to create `k`.

---

Having said that, there is an alternative method to efficiently achieve your desired final result using a bit of reshaping (without copying) and numpy's [`einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) function.

Here's an example.  First define `x` and `A`:

```
In [52]: x = np.arange(75).reshape(3, 5, 5)

In [53]: A = np.arange(90).reshape(10, 9)
```

Here's my understanding of what you want to achieve; `A.dot(k.T)` is the desired result:

```
In [54]: k = np.hstack(np.vstack(x)[:, 0:3].reshape(3, 5, 3))

In [55]: A.dot(k.T)
Out[55]: 
array([[ 1392,  1572,  1752,  1932,  2112],
       [ 3498,  4083,  4668,  5253,  5838],
       [ 5604,  6594,  7584,  8574,  9564],
       [ 7710,  9105, 10500, 11895, 13290],
       [ 9816, 11616, 13416, 15216, 17016],
       [11922, 14127, 16332, 18537, 20742],
       [14028, 16638, 19248, 21858, 24468],
       [16134, 19149, 22164, 25179, 28194],
       [18240, 21660, 25080, 28500, 31920],
       [20346, 24171, 27996, 31821, 35646]])
```

Here's how you can get the same result by slicing `x` and reshaping `A`:

```
In [56]: x2 = x[:,:,:3]

In [57]: A2 = A.reshape(-1, 3, 3)

In [58]: einsum('ijk,jlk', A2, x2)
Out[58]: 
array([[ 1392,  1572,  1752,  1932,  2112],
       [ 3498,  4083,  4668,  5253,  5838],
       [ 5604,  6594,  7584,  8574,  9564],
       [ 7710,  9105, 10500, 11895, 13290],
       [ 9816, 11616, 13416, 15216, 17016],
       [11922, 14127, 16332, 18537, 20742],
       [14028, 16638, 19248, 21858, 24468],
       [16134, 19149, 22164, 25179, 28194],
       [18240, 21660, 25080, 28500, 31920],
       [20346, 24171, 27996, 31821, 35646]])
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `np.einsum` function... thanks, that was informative. How can I use `np.einsum` with C to get my result using `cblas_sgemm`?

Comment: That I don't know.  If your program is a mix of Python and C, you could just leave this calculation in Python and use numpy.  If you are writing a pure C program (and you used numpy just to explain the issue), you'll probably have to use multiple calls to sgemm to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that... I did use numpy just to explain what my problem was. Basically, I'm passing these `ndarrays` straight into C using ctypes, using `cblas_sgemm` to get my result, and then reshape the result again in python. I figured that multiple calls / temporary buffers could be avoided if only I could come up with a smart way to reshape my input, so that one call to blas would be enough.